# How do I manually set the key-view in a cocoa app?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstextfield, first-responder

I have a cocoa app written in Swift. The app has a number of `NSControls` for user entries. The user can use the tab key to move between the controls, most of them being textfields. I am doing all in Code, I do not use the Interface Builder.

Some of them are dynamic: I have a custom `NSControl`, let's call it `myRow` which itself is hosting two ´NSTextFields´. myRow itself is hosted in a superView, let's call it `myRowManager`. When the user makes an entry this `myRow` notifies the `myRowManager`, and another `myRow` is placed below the first one. When one field's content is deleted by the user the `myRowManager` then deletes that `myRow` and re-arranges the remaining `myRows`. The whole setup is mimicking a table view, where there is always one more row than there are entries so that the user can always add an entry at the end.

Using the tab key when modifying existing entries works just fine.

But the nature of my setup means, that when a row is added or deleted a method `.layoutSubviews()` is called, there all `myRows` are removed from the superView (the manager) and then new `myRows` are created, reflecting the new number and order, which is of course reflecting the underlying data.

But by removing the myRow which just had the focus from the view hierarchy sets the window's initial responder as the `key-view`, as the current and next element in the `key-view loop` are no longer present.

I therefore am trying to set the `key-view` manually to the newly created textfield. To do this, a reference to this textfield is kept by the `layoutSubviews` method.

Unfortunately I have not been successful so far.

What I am doing now (this is the method of the manager which is called by a `myRow` when an entry is added):

```
func rowAddedAtEnd(_ index: Int) {
    layoutSubviews()
    self.window?.recalculateKeyViewLoop()
    self.window?.selectKeyView(following:targetView)
}
```

What strikes me as odd is that there is no method th set a specific view as the key view. I can either use `.selectKeyView(following:)` or `(preceding:)`

But anyway - it does not work. The focus ring just gets reset to the top left element in the window.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of `func selectKeyView(following view: NSView)`:

> Sends the `nextValidKeyView` message to `view` and, if that message returns an `NSView` object, invokes `makeFirstResponder(_:)` with the returned object.

To select `targetView`, skip `nextValidKeyView` and call `makeFirstResponder(_:)`.

```
self.window?.makeFirstResponder(targetView)
```

Comment: Ok, that would make things easier - if it would work as expected. Unfortunately I get the same result. The window doesn't get the view I pass and so defaults to the initial first responder.
Is there a way to debug which view is the current key view or have a look at the key-view loop as it is synthesized by the recalculate method in form of a list?

Comment: Is the view in the window? Can the view be first responder? Is something else setting the first responder? What does `makeFirstResponder` return? The current first responder is `self.window?.firstResponder`. The key-view loop isn't a list, inspect `nextKeyView` and `previousKeyView`. `makeFirstResponder` doesn't use the key-view loop.

Comment: Try `DispatchQueue.main.async {self.window?.makeFirstResponder(targetView)}`

Comment: Yeah, putting it on the main thread was the solution. I know that UIStaff must go on the main thread but I would never have guessed that this would be the cause.

Comment: It isn't the thread. `makeFirstResponder` is scheduled on the next iteration of the runloop, after AppKit has done its magic.